# How to pass the initial state as props for my Higher Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composite-component, higher-order-functions, recompose

I have a `Slider` component that doesn't handle its own state, instead, it's wrapped in another component called `SliderDrag` that manages the state and passes down props to the `Slider`

I'm using `withState` from `recompose` library to achieve that.

here is my `Slider` state initial state

```
export const getInitialState = () => ({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  value: 50,
  step: 1,
  width: 100,
  dragging: false
});
```

And here is my Higher Order Component from `withState()`

```
export const SliderDrag = withState('state', 'onChange', getInitialState())(
  ({state, onChange, action}) => (
  <Slider
  {...state}
  onDragStart={({x}) => {
    onChange(dragStart(x, state));
  }}
  onDrag={({x}) => {
    onChange(drag(x, state));
    action('value')(state.value);
  }}
  onDragEnd={() => {
    onChange(dragEnd(state));
  }}
 />
)
);
```

And here is how I want to use `SliderDrag`. I want to pass down props to set my initial `state` so that I can use this `Slider` component in different contexts in my app

```
export const interactive = (action) => (
  <Storypage theme={designerTheme}>
    <SliderDrag width={218} step={1} min={0} max={100} action={action}/>
  </Storypage>
);
```

Do I need to use `compose` from `recompose` library? Any advice or help would be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5):

With some help I was able to solve my problem.

I should pass a reference to the function that sets the `initialState` as the last argument to `withState()`, this way when `initialState` gets called, I will have access to the `props` I'm passing to my `SliderDrag` component

Here is how I refactored this

```
const initialState = ({min, max, step, width, value}) => {
  debugger;
  return defaults({min, max, step, width, value}, defaultState());
};

export const SliderDrag = withState('state', 'onChange', initialState)(
  ({state, onChange, action}) => (
      <Slider
      {...state}
      ...
      />
  )
);
```

`defaults` here just overrides the values I'm passing and gives me a new object as my `state`.

This makes my `component` configurable because any other `component` can use it and pass down `props` as the `initial state`